# variable out of scope but still works

Tags: python, for-loop, pytorch

I am following the pytorch tutorial [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/word_embeddings_tutorial.html) and got to the word embeddings tutorial but there is some code I do not understand.

When constructing n-grams they use the following:

```
ngrams = [
    (
        [test_sentence[i - j - 1] for j in range(CONTEXT_SIZE)],
        test_sentence[i]
    )
    for i in range(CONTEXT_SIZE, len(test_sentence))
]
```

This to me does not seem syntactically correct as `i` is referenced before it is initialized, there is nothing inside the `for` loop, and the `for` loop is missing the `:` at the end. What is going on with this block of code? It does not seem like it should work but it does.

Comment: That's a *list comprehension*, rather than a `for` loop.  The whole block of code inside the outermost square brackets is a single expression, the loop variable is available throughout that expression.

Comment: @jasonharper oh I see it now, the formatting makes it look strange.

Comment: You can see the language description at: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a syntax of python like you can define a list like this:

```
a_list = [i*2 for i in range(100)]
```

in your example it is defining a 2-D list, so there are two for loop
like:

```
b_list = [(a_list) for j in range(2)]
```

if we combine, we can write them like the example you posted.